# How to display math operators not in italic?

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

I'm trying to write the following equation:

```
\rho = \max \left\{ \frac{|\mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{x^{(i)}} + b|}{\|\mathbf{w}\|} \right\}
```

but the PDF output renders the math operator `\max` in italic instead of upright. I've tried the same with `\log` and `\cos`, and they behave just the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Document class: memoir

Packages: pgf, fontspec, graphicx, microtype, unicode-math, amsmath

The following code reproduces the problem in different systems:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Yay, a dual problem:
\begin{equation}
\max_{\mathbf{\alpha}} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha{(i)} \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  i'm afraid we don't have enough information to guess what the problem is, since the code you show looks correct.  please provide a small compilable example that produces the unwanted result, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` so that we can test it.

Comment: Probably it is effect of document class you are using.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use, and do tell us if you load any math-related packages.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've added some info to the post.

Comment: Looks like you're using LuaLaTeX to compile your document -- is this the case? If so, which math font do you use, i.e., what's the argument of `\setmathfont`?

Comment: I'm actually using XeLaTeX, the font is Latin Modern.

Comment: stop making everyone guess! it is impossible to help as you have shown no code that could account for the described behaviour. Make a small 5 or 6 line document, complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that has the problem, then people can easily reproduce and debug it.

Comment: Sorry for the brevity. Added some lines of code that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution: Load the `amsmath` package *before* the `unicode-math` package. (I think this is mentioned in the user guide of the `unicode-math` package...)

Comment: @soldeace - Glad to be of assistance. :-)